# Whether a sum over all partitions of n decays exponentially with n

Tags: asymptotics, integer-partitions

Given $L$ as an absolute constant (does not depend on $n$), and $\beta$ is a function of $n$. Consider

$$\sum_{m_1+\cdots+m_k=n\\ 1\leq k\leq L\\ \text{all }m_i \text{ are positive integers}}\binom{L}{k}k!\binom{n}{m_1,\cdots,m_k}\exp(-\frac{\binom{n}{2}-(\binom{m_1}{2}+\cdots+\binom{m_k}{2})}{2\beta})$$

where $\binom{1}{2}$ is set as $0$.

Is it possible to find the condition of $\beta(n)$ (it has to be positive and increasing with $n$), such that the above summation over all partitions (the order of $(m_1,\cdots,m_k)$ does not matter) of $n$, is exponentially decaying when $n$ grows, for example, ~$\exp(-cn)$ where $c$ is certain absolute constant.

Comment: $\sum_{m_i}\binom Lk k!\binom{m}{m_1,\dots,m_k} f(m_1,\dots,m_k,k,L,n)$ can be written as $$\sum_{\pi} F(\pi,L,n)$$ where $\pi$ runs over all ways of writing $\{1,2,\dots,n\}=A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots A_L$ into $L$ disjoint (but possibly empty) sets and $$F(\pi,L,n)=f(m_1,\dots,m_k,k,L,n)$$ where $k$ is the number of non-empty $A_i$  and $m_i$ are the sizes of the non-empty parts of $\pi.$ Not sure how that helps, but this seems more naturally a question about such unions. The numerator of the exponent is the number of pairs from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that are not both members of the same $A_i.$

Comment: Se we can think of $\pi$ as any function $\pi:[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to [L]=\{1,2,\dots,L\},$ and $$g(\pi)=\left|\{\{a,b\}\subseteq [n]\mid \pi(a)\neq \pi(b)\}\right|.$$ Then your formula is: $$\sum_{\pi:[n]\to[L]}\exp(g(\pi)/\beta(n))$$ Of course, this can be seen as setting $\alpha_n=\exp(1/\beta(n))$ and this becomes a question about: $$\sum_\pi \alpha_n^{g(\pi)}.$$ Since $g(\pi)$ is a natural number, this makes it a question about integer polynomials: $$P_{n,L}(x)=\sum_\pi x^{g(\pi)}$$ with $P(0)=L,$ $P(1)=L^n.$

Comment: It seems like you'll need $\beta(n)$ to be negative, otherwise $\alpha_n>1$ and $P$ is increasing, so $P(\alpha_n)>L^n,$ which makes it hard for that value to decay.

Comment: And yes, I should have had $\alpha_n=\exp(1/(2\beta(n))).$ Basically, you'll need $\alpha_n\to 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\beta(n)$ has to be positive and increasing.. I just plot the value of the summation, I plug in $\beta(n)=n/(2 \log(n))$ and let $n$ varies from $3$ to $50$, $L=30$, the summation starts to decreasing after $n>6$ (but seems remains equal after $n>23$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I made a huge mistake! The thing in $\exp$ has a minus sign! so it is $\exp(-\frac{\binom{n}{2}-(\binom{m_1}{2}+\cdots+\binom{m_k}{2})}{2\beta})$ instead of $\exp(\frac{\binom{n}{2}-(\binom{m_1}{2}+\cdots+\binom{m_k}{2})}{2\beta})$

Comment: For $n=2$, are $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ valid $(m_i)$ sequences in the sum, or only $(2)$ and $(1,1)$?

Comment: @aschepler I will add $m_i\neq 0$ in my post! thanks!